# Play sound on location change echo

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am checking current location with google maps api.

When location changes I am playing sound If current location has a value grather than 15 meters.

What happening is that the sound seems to start multiple times and makes an echo effect

I am using 
    mediaFile.start ();

For my declared mediaFile

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a service class which will get the user's current GPS values and implement onLocationChangeListener on the service.

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
      //calculate distance values between initial location and current location
     if(distance>15){
           play_sound();
     }
}

 public void play_sound() {
    // Initializing
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound_file_name);
    mp.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mp.release();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: I Will look in to your code. The problem is not that its not playing when location change its the opposite, so I Will try to add timer and see If the echo problem dissapears